# Spinner in Toolbar Example in Xamarin for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-spinner

I am trying to implement a spinner in the toolbar of my navigation drawer.
My initial toolbar layout included the following xml code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/languagetoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

      <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_languageSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/array_languageSelect"
        android:gravity="right" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The thing is that there does not seem to exist to be an example that seem to show the implementation method using Xamarin. I have tried to use the following resources :
  https://dabx.io/2015/01/02/material-design-spinner-toolbar-style-fix/  &
  http://android-pratap.blogspot.co.za/2015/01/spinner-in-toolbar-example-in-android.html
x
  The short comings of the two examples is that using Xamarin I have found that I cannot use .setAdapter as it only exists as an interface
The look that i want in the tool bar is similar to the image in the first link but having the spinner to the extreme right.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I finally found is explained perfectly by prathap in http://android-pratap.blogspot.co.za/2015/01/spinner-in-toolbar-example-in-android.html. The solution involves adding the spinner to the toolbar layout like below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/languagetoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


    <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_languageSpinner"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:entries="@array/array_languageSelect"
      style="@style/MyTheme"
      android:gravity="right" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then the code that follows will require the user to populate the spinner in the code from their activity.